# Why is the phase angle in the summation of the phasors the negative arctan?

Tags: phasor

I was reading a textbook and came across the following

$$
\\I_1 = Ae^{j0} = A
\\I_2 = Be^{-j\frac{\pi}{2}}
\\\bf{I} = I_1 + I_2
\\If\ A=10\ and\ B=20
\\|I| = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}
\\\angle I = -tan^{-1}(B/A)
\\I = 27.98e^{j30.4^{\circ}}
$$

From my knowledge, of complex numbers, shouldn't \$\angle\bf{I} \$ be  \$\angle \bf{I} = tan^{-1}(B/A)\$ since both B and A are in the first quadrant?

Comment: You can't just use the values of A and B since they are magnitudes of the phasor. They will always be positive since they are magnitudes.

Answer (score 1):

I = A - jB is a complex number and it is in the fourth quadrant. So argument of **I** must be negative.
Mind that **I_2** has angle -pi/2.

Answer (score 1):

Positive x and negative y means Quadrant IV.

[image]

\$\vec {I_1} = 10\ ∡ 0^\circ\ A\$

\$\vec {I_2} = 20\ ∡ - \frac {\pi} {2}\ A  = 20\ ∡ - 90^\circ\ A \$

\$\vec {I_1} + \vec {I_2} = 10 - j20\ A = 22.36\ ∡ -63.43^\circ\ A \$

This does not agree with your \$ 27.98\ e^{j30.4^\circ} \$, but that is the math.

y is larger than x, so angle has to be greater than \$45^\circ\$.